# Unity Android build gives DirectoryNotFoundException for file in Application.streamingAssetsPath

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an application with a SQLite embedded database. In the editor and the build of PC accesses the database without problems. However, when it comes to the build of Android, I test it on a device and for some reason unknown to me is not working.

I followed the steps of some official forum guides. I have also added the plugins folder of this project:

https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d

Despite this, I still can not run the database after the build.

```
conn = (Applicaiton.streamingAssetsPath + "/Database.sqlite");
filepath = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.sqlite");
WWW dbPath = new WWW(conn);
while (!dbPath.isDone) {}

byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dbPath.url);
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, bytes);
connection = ("URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.sqlite");
dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(connection);
```

I pulled log data with ADB and found this:

```
06-01 22:29:05.180: I/Unity(5835): DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/jar:file:/data/app/com.Company.App-1.apk!/assets/Database.sqlite"
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error or exception? What step is failing?

Comment: Hi, the application does not show any error in the editor and the PC build. However, when I do the build and run  on any Android device fails something. It is somewhat akin to the database, either by any path or something else. Is it possible to display a log where possible errors, if any, while I run it on an Android device? Thanls.

Comment: You can use ADB to pull logs from the device. Recommend making a development build of your Unity project for more log data. There are tutorials online that cover this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks man, i saved the log from eclipse and logcat. This seems to be the reason for the failure: 06-01 22:29:05.180: I/Unity(5835): DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/jar:file:/data/app/com.Company.App-1.apk!/assets/Database.sqlite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Unity manual page on streaming assets](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html):

> Note that on Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to retrieve the file then you will need to use additional software to see inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

Your problem is here:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dbPath.url);
```

On Android builds, `Application.streamingAssetsPath` maps to a location within your compressed APK file. Unity's `WWW` class will internally recognize and handle this, but `System.IO` does not have that behavior built in.

You can use the `WWW` class to extract the file's bytes:

```
while (!dbPath.isDone) {}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath.error)) {
    //handle www error?
} else {
    byte[] bytes = dbPath.bytes;
    //do something with the data
}
```

Bear in mind that you've made this a blocking operation, which may affect game performance. If that's a problem, you can refactor to handle all of this asynchronously.

Comment: You rock! That worked for me! Tomorrow I will try to do the build for iOS and come up with more problems, almost sure hehe. Thanks.

Comment: Hi rutter i'm having lil problem also on my side could you please take a look at my problem here's the [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154791/invalid-character-in-input-string-at-litjson-lexer-nexttoken)